# Android - Implement a Instagram-like Edittext box

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am working on an Android app and I am going to implement a EditBox which will very like the Instagram one showing below:

Like the screen capture below, the area marked by the red line is a whole edit box (which means click anywhere, even the image, the editbox will get focus and keyboard will show up.) but only the right side of the blue line is the input text area.

[Instagram Editbox http://snag.gy/CTWsK.jpg](http://snag.gy/CTWsK.jpg)

The code I currently have is pretty trivial

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:hint="Ho shot man"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_weight="1" />       
</LinearLayout>
```

and drawable is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />

  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

I am not sure whether there is a layout cascade workaround I could do to make the editbox like the Instagram one, or if I need to extend the editbox to change its behavior? Pointers or code sample will be greatly helpful, thank you!

Comment: you need the drawable at the left side of the EditText??

Comment: Check out my answer and try accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editthis"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editbox"
                    android:hint="this this this"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#999999"
                     android:textSize="14dip"                          
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Drawable left the icon will be set in left side

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great. An extra little question on this not sure if you could help: like the Instagram example, this is a multiline edittext box and the first line start from the top of the box. My current code can only have the text vertically centered in the middle of the box. How I can let the text start from the top left corner? Thanks!

Comment: Set the gravity of your Edittext to the Top & Left`android:gravity="top|left" and will start from top.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for one more quick question: I did some search but did not find a way to define the size of android:drawableLeft. Is there a way to fix the size of this image? I was wondering if I can set the image size to be, say, 100x100, so that bigger image will be cropped and smaller image will be stretched accordingly.

Comment: Well actually AFAIK there is no way to fix the size of image. Its better you make the image of your required resolution and set it in edittext.